# $H^{1/2}(0,1)$ and continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

It is known that $H^s(0,1)$ embeds into Hoelder continuous functions for $s>1/2$. I am not interested in Hoelder continuity, but merely in continuity: do I get the continuous embedding $H^{1/2}(0,1)\subseteq C([0,1])$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951180/fractional-sobolev-space-h1-2-pi-pi.